# EhCache: Choosing Eviction Policy

Tags: java, caching, benchmarking, ehcache

EhCache comes with the ability to choose an *eviction policy* for when a cache fills up to its maximum size. This eviction policy is used to determine which elements to "evict" from the cache so that it does not overflow.

The three eviction policy options for on-heap memory stores are:

- LFU (Least Frequently Used) - the default
- LRU (Least Recently Used)
- FIFO (First In, First Out)

My question is: **how does one determine which one of these policies is most effective for a particular application**? Obviously, each will have their own strengths and weaknesses, and different applications will fair better or worse with each of these depending on numerous factors.

Is there a benchmark that can be setup? I'd love to write a performance test, but wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to test with your own code/data, than try do guess without full information.
Write a sample code, that generate data (data should be as close as possible to your real samples, it could be stored in database, or send to your app using messages, depending on it's workflow). After it try to write a simple code, that will use read/write methods, that are used by application and test it with all 3 strategies.